# Worklight WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe not getting fired

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I am facing an issue with Worklight Push Notification.

I followed all steps of Worklight 5.0.5, Module_41_-_Push_Notifications.
PDF  file, and did Push demo.

I am facing an error stating:

> [ERROR] Can't subscribe, notification token is not updated on the
>   server

Although on the console it does show the device ID. 
My assumption is **WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe** not getting fired.

Someone had similar issues.
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=456501

I have set

```
<pushSender password="Your_Password"/>
```

and re-generated and deployed App multiple times but no benefit.

Any help or suggestion are welcome.

```
Environment:
WL 5.0.5 & 5.0.6
Xcode 4.2
iPhone (iOS 5.1 and 6.1)
```

I tried once again on local mac, testing via iPhone 4 , iOS 5.1. when running through device and connecting to Studio jetty. I am getting below.

```
Mar 27 11:23:49 Appsdev-iPhone PushApplication[211] <Warning>: Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
Mar 27 11:23:49 Appsdev-iPhone PushApplication[211] <Warning>: Web resources integrity test is disabled.
Mar 27 11:23:49 Appsdev-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[211] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
Mar 27 11:23:49 Appsdev-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[211] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/5DA837C4-F039-4795-9509-C98383E40C68 [69] (sandbox)
Mar 27 11:23:49 Appsdev-iPhone PushApplication[211] <Warning>: Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
Mar 27 11:23:51 Appsdev-iPhone PushApplication[211] <Warning>: [LOG] ondeviceready event dispatched
Mar 27 11:23:51 Appsdev-iPhone PushApplication[211] <Warning>: {
        appVersionPref = "1.0";
        freeSpace = 14291787776;
        wlSkinLoaderChecksum = "(null)";
        wlSkinName = default;
    }
Mar 27 11:23:51 Appsdev-iPhone PushApplication[211] <Warning>: [LOG] wlclient init started
Mar 27 11:23:51 Appsdev-iPhone PushApplication[211] <Warning>: [LOG] Read cookies: null
Mar 27 11:23:51 Appsdev-iPhone PushApplication[211] <Warning>: [LOG] CookieMgr read cookies: {}
Mar 27 11:23:51 Appsdev-iPhone PushApplication[211] <Warning>: [LOG] Request [http://172.20.10.2:8080/apps/services/api/PushApplication/iphone/init]
Mar 27 11:24:12 Appsdev-iPhone PushApplication[211] <Warning>: [LOG] Request [login]
Mar 27 11:24:12 Appsdev-iPhone PushApplication[211] <Warning>: [LOG] Request [http://172.20.10.2:8080/apps/services/api/PushApplication/iphone/init]
Mar 27 11:24:12 Appsdev-iPhone PushApplication[211] <Warning>: DeviceAuthManager:getWorklightUniqueDeviceId --> returning UUID from the keychain
Mar 27 11:24:12 Appsdev-iPhone PushApplication[211] <Warning>: [LOG] Request [http://172.20.10.2:8080/apps/services/api/PushApplication/iphone/init]
Mar 27 11:24:12 Appsdev-iPhone PushApplication[211] <Warning>: [LOG] Clearing notification subscriptions.
Mar 27 11:24:12 Appsdev-iPhone PushApplication[211] <Warning>: [LOG] Send new server notification token id.
Mar 27 11:24:12 Appsdev-iPhone SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: No valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application 'PushApplication': (null). Notifications will not be delivered.
Mar 27 11:24:12 Appsdev-iPhone PushApplication[211] <Warning>: [LOG] response [http://172.20.10.2:8080/apps/services/api/PushApplication/iphone/init] success: /*-secure-
    {"userPrefs":{},"WL-Authentication-Success":{"wl_remoteDisableRealm":{"userId":"null","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"null"},"PushAppRealm":{"userId":"aahad","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"aahad"},"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"userId":"3l6ap8g9t4h9uk5rb1fmqfok15","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"3l6ap8g9t4h9uk5rb1fmqfok15"},"wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm":{"userId":"57B167E4-1258-4AD7-9DA1-92DC66A0451E","attributes":{"mobileClientData":"com.worklight.core.auth.impl.MobileClientData@6a76de98"},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"57B167E4-1258-4AD7-9DA1-92DC66A0451E"}},"notificationSubscriptionState":{},"gadgetProps":{"directUpdate":{"updateUnpackedSize":1014255,"availableSkins":["default"],"checksum":4077143359,"updateSize":290080},"ENVIRONMENT":"iphone"},"userInfo":{"wl_authenticityRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null},"SampleAppRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null},"wl_remoteDisableRealm":{"userId":"null","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"null"},"PushAppRealm":{"userId":"aahad","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"aahad"},"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"userId":"3l6ap8g9t4h9uk5rb1fmqfok15","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"3l6ap8g9t4h9uk5rb1fmqfok15"},"WorklightConsole":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null},"wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null},"wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm":{"userId":"57B167E4-1258-4AD7-9DA1-92DC66A0451E","attributes":{"mobileClientData":"com.worklight.core.auth.impl.MobileClientData@6a76de98"},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"57B167E4-1258-4AD7-9DA1-92DC66A0451E"},"myserver":{"userId":"aahad","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"aahad"},"wl_anonymousUserRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null}}}*/

Mar 27 11:24:12 Appsdev-iPhone PushApplication[211] <Warning>: [LOG] wlclient connect success
Mar 27 11:24:12 Appsdev-iPhone PushApplication[211] <Warning>: [LOG] before: app init onSuccess
Mar 27 11:24:12 Appsdev-iPhone PushApplication[211] <Warning>: [LOG] after: app init onSuccess
Mar 27 11:24:12 Appsdev-iPhone PushApplication[211] <Warning>: [LOG] wlclient init success
Mar 27 11:24:12 Appsdev-iPhone PushApplication[211] <Warning>: Could not register for remote notifications: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0xfeafba0 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}
Mar 27 11:24:12 Appsdev-iPhone PushApplication[211] <Warning>: [ERROR] Error while trying to retrieve device token from the mobile operating system.
```

see attached snapshots.[image]
[image]

The steps to generate APNS:

- Logged on to Apple Account select App ID ->Configure -> Enable Push
- Selected Development Push SSL Certificate
- Generated a new CSR first and then got a Certificate
- Double clicked the certificate and from Keychain selected this new Certificate and its Private key, and then right-click and Export and saved as
  apns-certificate-sandbox.p12
- copied into Worklight, on the root of App folder at the same level of application-descriptor.xml
- provided pushSender password and given securityTest

Thanks

Comment: Edit your post with more information: which environment? iOS or Android (which OS version in the case of Android).

Comment: Did you add a push-enabled certificate to your project? Are you signing your application in Xcode with push-enabled signing identity?

Comment: Yes i have provided a Push-enabled certificate and am referring to a correct Distribution certificate. I hope you mean this by "signing your application in Xcode with push-enabled signing identity?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Idan,

Its resolved now. There were two reasons:

1. After copying APNS certificate inside the worklight App folder, you have to re-generate & deploy all. You must then deploy wlapp on WL consle....... that is was NOT doing.
2. I used a wrong custom security realm for iPhone environment that blocked the WL Server to response back to device.

Hope this info will help others facing similar issues.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @AAhad how did you regenerate and deploy all?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have:

1. Added the iPhone environment to application-descriptor.xml (using the Worklight-provided wizard)
2. Added the mobile securityTest to the iphone environment (see how it is done for the Android environment; copy it)
3. Placed the .p12 certificate in the application folder (same level as the environment folders)
4. That the name of the certificate is "apns-certificate-sandbox.p12" (for development) or "apns-certificate-production.p12" (for production)
5. Added the correct password in the pushSender element

After logging-in in the application, you should get an alert stating that you are able to subscribe.

To make sure you have properly setup your development environment, follow this guide: [Understanding and setting up artifacts required to use iOS devices and Apple Push Notifications services (APNS) in development environment](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/understanding-and-setting-up-push-notifications-in-development-evnironment?lang=en)

Comment: Yes @Idan, I did the same way.

Comment: As can be seen in the log you've added: <Warning>: No valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application 'PushApplication': (null). Notifications will not be delivered -- something is not right in your setup. Are you sure you are using the correct bundleId in Xcode, and that it is matching the signing identity you choose (also in Xcode)? Follow this guide: http://goworklight.wordpress.com/2013/03/20/understanding-and-setting-up-artifacts-required-to-use-ios-devices-and-apple-push-notifications-services-apns-in-development-environment/

Comment: indeed it looks correct bundle ID I provided. I re-tested locally running App on mac, but no success. Now i am checking my client's App that is in UAT phase.......meanwhile if any other step you want to confirm, plz let me know? Or anything you want i can share here...thanks